# move activity to fragment using position

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had used two imagebuttons to perform onClick to move to fragment page.Workflow for Activity : GridActivity1->HomeActivity->ShortFragment and DetailFragment.

For that I set a position to move HomeActivity and then call the listener method to move appropriate fragment.

**GridActivity1.java:**

```
  int position;

  case R.id.btn_tour:

                Intent i1=new Intent(GridActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);


                i1.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i1);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_contact:

                Intent i2=new Intent(GridActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);

                i2.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ArticleSelectedListener {

 int position;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 position= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

  if(position==0){

           onArticleSelected(2, "Short Fragment");

       }
        if(position==1){

           onArticleSelected(10, "Detail Fragment");
       }

 @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position, String content)
    {
 if(position==2)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ShortFragment newFragment = new ShortFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
       //     ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

  if(position==10)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
      //      ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

My only issue is, For ShortFragment it is working fine.Same thing I did it in Detail Fragment class,it is not working.

I don't know how to set a position for second fragment.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check GridActivity1.java position variable .

do it

case R.id.btn_tour:

```
            Intent i1=new Intent(GridActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);


            i1.putExtra("position", 0);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_contact:

            Intent i2=new Intent(GridActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);

            i2.putExtra("position", 1);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(position==0){

       onArticleSelected(position, "Short Fragment");

   }
    if(position==1){

       onArticleSelected(position, "Detail Fragment");
   }

@Override
public void onArticleSelected(int n, String content)
{
if(n==0)
    {
        action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ShortFragment newFragment = new ShortFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
   //     ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

if(n==1)
    {
        action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
  //      ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: I cant change like that.Because in navigation drawer I am using like this.`case 9: onArticleSelected(10, "Detail Fragment"); break;    case 3: onArticleSelected(2, "Short Fragment");`

Answer (score 0):

Your position in GridActivity1 is always set to zero thats the Reason only ShortFragment is working and not DetailFragment.